# Laravel migration error: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I got the following error. How can I fix it?

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'account_infos'

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('account_info', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
        $table->foreign('users_id')->references('id')
            ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('axis_id');
        $table->foreign('axis_id')->references('id')
            ->on('axis')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->enum('account_type',['legal','rightful']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have another migrations that reference to `account_infos`?

Comment: Do you get the error when running migration or working with routes or ..?

Comment: Migration is successful but gives an error message when I try to call the forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add:

```
    protected $table='account_info';
```

in your model

Comment: He says the error is in migration, not Model. At least this is what he says! But I think you are right somehow, he does not know where he is facing the problem!!